# Late 2020 Mac mini, windows keep resizing and moving upon wake from sleep or screen off

Tags: display, sleep-wake, mac-mini

I have a Late 2020 Mac mini running whatever the latest 11.x.x is.  It's hooked via HDMI directly into a 32" Asus monitor.  Whenever I restart - which isn't common - or wake the computer from the display being off (not the computer asleep because I have weather software connected to a weather sensor that uploads to Wunderground), windows move and resize, typically moving to the bottom-left ≈1/4 of the display, as though the OS doesn't detect the monitor right away and tries to move things around to compensate.

This phenomenon is hit-or-miss depending on the application and depending on whether it is hidden or not.  So, I just tested it again, and Safari, Finder, Keynote, and Excel all stayed put (not hidden).  But, VLC moved.  Then, if I do something like hide Safari and put the display to sleep, then wake it up, all my Safari windows are on top of each other in that bottom-left ~quarter of the display.

I'm a bit OCD with where I place windows and how I have them sized, so it's a fairly continuous frustration not being able to hide things when working on certain tasks or needing to move stuff back after coming back to the computer, and then if I do forget and hide something needing to re-move and resize them all when I come back.

I thought this might be an issue with the M1 chip, or the macOS 11, but we're now over half a year in and this is still a major issue for me, so maybe someone can help? (I've not owned a Mac mini before, but I've had several headless Mac desktops and this was never an issue)

Comment: See if manually waking the screen before you 'wake' the Mac makes any difference. Sometimes they don't 'sign in' fast enough for the Mac to recognise what they are. Alternatively, try a DisplayPort or USB-C connection [or even DVI at a push], if they're available. HDMI is pretty clumsy compared to the 'pro' connections.

Comment: Manually waking the display didn't work (just tried).  The Mac minis have only HDMI as native, though I have a CalDigit hub that looks like it has a DisplayPort.  However, I currently have that hooked into a Hackintosh since HDMI wasn't working well on that, and this monitor only has one DisplayPort input.  I'll see if I can try it for academic reasons later today, though.